# How to get last 90 days monday to sunday date?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

How to get last 90 days monday to sunday date.

```
S.no    Start_dt    End_dt  week
1   18-Jul-16   24-Jul-16   Week1
2   25-Jul-16   31-Jul-16   Week2
3   1-Aug-16    7-Aug-16    Week3
4   8-Aug-16    14-Aug-16   Week4
5   15-Aug-16   21-Aug-16   Week5
6   22-Aug-16   28-Aug-16   Week6
7   29-Aug-16   4-Sep-16    Week7
8   5-Sep-16    11-Sep-16   Week8
9   12-Sep-16   18-Sep-16   Week9
10  19-Sep-16   25-Sep-16   Week10
11  26-Sep-16   2-Oct-16    Week11
12  3-Oct-16    9-Oct-16    Week12
13  10-Oct-16   16-Oct-16   Week13
```

We need to use sysdate as input.
I am trying below query it return current week monday ,sunday date

> SELECT   TRUNC(sysdate, 'D') +1 startofweek, TRUNC(sysdate, 'D') + 7
>   endofweek FROM dual;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select trunc(sysdate-(13-rownum)*7, 'iw') start_dt, trunc(sysdate-(12-rownum)*7, 'iw')-1 end_dt, 'week'||rownum week 
from dual 
connect by rownum<=90/7+1
```

Comment: Any idea is't Possible in Redshift? select trunc(date_trunc('week',sysdate)) st_dt,trunc(date_trunc('week', sysdate)+6) ed_dt